# Help me to understand the answer given

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have problem with UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl when i rotate the device beacuse the curl is not rotating as i expected and i found the below extract of the answer but i am not able to undertsand.

i am not sure how to create a "rootviewcontroller" Property as told like below

So i am looking for your guidence to proceed further .I am really stuck with this thing for long days...

Thanks for any help:-

---

**The SOURCE CODE I HAVE**

```
//
//  ModalViewExampleViewController.h
//  ModalViewExample
//
//  Created by Tim Neill on 11/09/10.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ModalViewExampleViewController : UIViewController {
    UIButton *showDefaultButton, *showFlipButton, *showDissolveButton, *showCurlButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *showDefaultButton, *showFlipButton, *showDissolveButton, *showCurlButton;

- (IBAction)showDefault:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showFlip:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showDissolve:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showCurl:(id)sender; 

@end 

//
//  ModalViewExampleViewController.m
//  ModalViewExample
//
//  Created by Tim Neill on 11/09/10.
//

#import "ModalViewExampleViewController.h"
#import "SampleViewController.h"

@implementation ModalViewExampleViewController

@synthesize showDefaultButton, showFlipButton, showDissolveButton, showCurlButton;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
} 

- (IBAction)showDefault:(id)sender {
    SampleViewController *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)showFlip:(id)sender {
    SampleViewController *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)showDissolve:(id)sender {
    SampleViewController *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)showCurl:(id)sender {
    SampleViewController *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    sampleView.rootViewController = self;

    [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
} 

- (void)dealloc {
    [showDefaultButton release];
    [showFlipButton release];
    [showDissolveButton release];
    [showCurlButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end

//
//  SampleViewController.h
//  ModalViewExample
//
//  Created by Tim Neill on 11/09/10.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class RootViewController;

@interface SampleViewController : UIViewController {

    RootViewController *rootViewController;

    UIButton *dismissViewButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *dismissViewButton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) RootViewController *rootViewController;


- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender;

@end 

//
//  SampleViewController.m
//  ModalViewExample
//
//  Created by Tim Neill on 11/09/10.
//

#import "SampleViewController.h"


@implementation SampleViewController

@synthesize rootViewController;

@synthesize dismissViewButton;

- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [dismissViewButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return YES;
} 
@end
```

[UIView Animation: PartialCurl ...bug during rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644782/uiview-animation-partialcurl-bug-during-rotate)

> I too had this issue and somewhat gave up. However, I mentioned my
>   dilemma to a friend, who encouraged me to look into the child VC's
>   logic and I recalled a handy trick that I've used to pass data between
>   parent/child view controllers.
>
> In your flipside view controller, create a "rootViewController"
>   property. In your parent view controller, when you initialize the
>   flipside view controller, you set (where "self" is the rootVC):
>
> ```
> flipsideController.rootViewController = self;
> ```
>
> You then use this for your flipside VC's
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method:
>
> -
>   (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
>   { return interfaceOrientation ==
>   self.rootViewController.interfaceOrientation;
>
> }
>
> Viola! The flipside view no longer rotates underneath the partially
>   curled up parent view!

Comment: Presumably you create a VC from within another VC. You store a pointer to the creating VC in the created VC under any name you like (rootViewController in this case) and, when you receive a shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: call, you check if rotation is the same as the creating VC.

To do that you will need to create a property for the creating VC, something like `@property (nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *rootViewController;` and corresponding instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

@From the post : *In your flipside view controller, create a "rootViewController" property.*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ModalViewExampleViewController;

@interface flipSideViewController : UIViewController {

    ModalViewExampleViewController *rootViewController;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ModalViewExampleViewController *rootViewController;

@end
```

and in your flipSideViewController's implementation file

```
#import "ModalViewExampleViewController.h"

@synthesize rootViewController;
```

Comment: You are trying to assign a ModalViewExampleViewController instance to rootViewController instance which will give you an error. SampleViewController.rootViewController = self; If you want a ModalViewExampleViewController property there change the rootViewController in the flipSideViewController as ModalViewExampleViewController.

Comment: @Elanthiirayan : Thanks for the reply dude..can you pls show me that in the source code where i m doing wrong.

Comment: Updated my code, My code will only help you to declare a property of one class in another. Please be aware that to solve your curl issue you should follow the answer you mentioned.